# Windows command line globbing with full path

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, command-line-interface

I know that I can do basic globbing that prints me the full path like so: `for %f in (pattern) do @echo %~dpnxf`

However, if I do `c:\dev>for %f in ("src/*.c") do @echo %~dpnxf`, where with the pattern I'm searching within a subdirectory, instead of getting `c:\dev\src\main.c` I'm only getting `c:\dev\main.c` as a result. It basically doesn't include the any subdirectory in the `p` modifier.

I'm now stuck on that for longer than I'd like to admit... Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `cd /D %windir%\..&for %f in ("windows\exp*.exe") do @echo %~dpnxf` works.
- `cd /D %windir%\..&for %f in ("windows/exp*.exe") do @echo %~dpnxf` does not work.

I guess `/` is a problem. Just use the real path separator on Windows which is `\`.